# how to install program that i made in VS2008 (FW3.5) on computer that has FW2.0?

Tags: entity-framework

is it possible to install program that i made in VS2008 (FW3.5) on computer that has FW2.0 ?

i need it because FW3.5 weight 130Mb and FW2.0 only 24Mb

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to include the needed files from FW 3.5 into the application directory (just activate "local copy" in the ressources for these files.

Comment: i don't think that i include any FW 3.5 component
how to convert project to FW 2.0 ?

Comment: Ok, what about this: Go to your project's settings, choose "compile" on the left and "advanced compilation options" on the bottom. Now you are able to set your destination framework version (2.0, 3.0, 3.5).
This should at least show you which of your used components are available in 2.0.
Maybe the button captions look different, don't have the english version.